# go 1.5 : Is "go install" behaviour changed? Removing stale executables?

Tags: bash, go

Till Go 1.4.2 when i run go install after running go build, i could find binary file in my current folder. Hence following Linux command was working

> $ go build && go install && ./executable

But after installing go 1.5, when i run same command i get,

> -bash: ./executable: No such file or directory

and when i checked, there is no executable to find. Did go install behavior changed in Go 1.5?

Comment: (Not an answer but still...) IIUC, you're not supposed to ever call `go build` if you're using `go install`. I mean, `go build` is for one-off builds while `go install` is what anyone should use for edit-run-reedit workflow. While this might be counter-intuitive for people coming from different environments (the verb "install" suggests `go install` is sort of *final* i.e. *deployment* step), in fact `go install` reuses already compiled *dependent* packages while `go build` recompiles the whole thing each time and then throws the intermediate object files away.

Comment: i completely agree with you @kostix. I use go build to to generate builds and test immediately but without doing go install, go build takes lot's of time to build every time.

Comment: Moreover point is whether go install behavior is changed or not.

Comment: @MayankPatel, if `go build` takes longer than `go install` it's almost certainly because you have un-installed dependencies (you can run `go build -v` to see what it's doing). Doing either `go install` *or* `go build -i` should install the dependant packages such that further `go build`s will only need to build things that have changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the behaviour has [changed](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/10682/) in Go 1.5:

> If 'go install' (with no arguments, meaning the current directory) succeeds, remove the executable written by 'go build', if present. This avoids leaving a stale binary behind during a sequence like:
>
> ```
> go build
> <test, mostly works, make small change>
> go install
> ```
>
> Before this CL, the current directory still has the stale binary from 'go build'. If $PATH contains dot, running the name of the program will find this stale binary instead of the new, installed one.

I can't find anything mentioning that in the [release notes](http://golang.org/doc/go1.5) though. Might be a documentation issue.

It seems like the solution is to use the binary that `go install` has produced.

**EDIT:** [Here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12288) is the issue on the Go issue tracker if you want to follow on updates. Should be fixed by 1.5.1.